# Can't install docker support in VS-2017 Community

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set Docker support in VS-2017 Community, but the item “.NET Core and Docker (Preview)” does not appear in visual studio installer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to ASP.NET and web development section. Hopefully you will find container development tools.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install Docker directly from Visual Studio. Just download and install the Docker .NET Core version from Docker Hub at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-nightly-sdk/ and add it to your Visual Studio project's path.